# AngularJS routing with id parameter ends in white page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

```
var app = angular.module('application', [ 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'assets/views/home.php',
            controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/dev', {
            templateUrl : 'assets/views/dev.php',   
            controller  : 'devCtrl'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/dev/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'assets/views/dev.php',
            controller  : 'devCtrl'
        });

});

app.run(function($rootScope, $window, $location, $route, $templateCache) {  
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {

    });
});
```

Im using the above angular to route my pages. I am trying to access a URL with a param and all I'm getting is a white page. `http://domain.com/dev/1234`

Have I missed something out here?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console via the dev tools of the browser your using?  Also, you've probably verified this, but just in case, is assets/views/dev.php accessible and do the other routes work?

Comment: @nstehr I posted an answer to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to put a `/` at the start of my `templateUrl`

The console.log error was showing that it was trying to load angular again.

```
var app = angular.module('application', [ 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/views/home.php',
            controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/dev', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/views/dev.php',   
            controller  : 'devCtrl'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/dev/:id', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/views/dev.php',
            controller  : 'devCtrl'
        });

});

app.run(function($rootScope, $window, $location, $route, $templateCache) {  
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {

    });
});
```